# How do I configure a virtual alias for VERP in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, alias

I want to use VERP to handle email bounces for my web application which does list emails.

Can postfix alias map use wildcards?

I want to have a catch-all account for bounces only, so could I have something like

```
bounce-catch+*@mydomain.com bouncecatch
```

so that every bounce-catch+recipeint=email.com@mydomain.com goes to bouncecatch?

Do I even have to do this or will postfix handle it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This is all described in http://www.postfix.org/VERP_README.html

So yes, you can have `bounce-catch@mydomain.com bouncecatch` in your virtual_alias_maps. See that there is no asterisk and no plus on the left-hand side because the plus already implies the asterisk.